# Split array in a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, arguments

```
<script>

window.onload = start;

function start() {
word(["S"+"U"+"Z"],["D"+"A"+"R"])

}

function word(a,b) {

 var letters = a+b
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
}
document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML=letters
}
</script>
```

Okay so this code works completely fine. My letters come out as "SUZDAR", but i wanna be able to remove the "+" symbol in my argument "Word" and replace it with commas. so the argument becomes (["S","U","Z"],["D","A","R"]). The question is, how do i remove the commas and get the same output as i currently have without the "+" symbols. I dont know how to use the split function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `join` function:

```
var letters = a.join('') + b.join('');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, could you explain short what the join(' ') does?

Comment: Join will concatenation the items in the array, placing the argument of the function between each item. The result will be a string. For example, [1,2,3].join(‘xx’) will be ‘1xx2xx3’

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge the 2 arrays and [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to merge array items to string

```js
function word(a,b){
 return a.concat(b).join('')
}

console.log(word(["S","U","Z"],["D","A","R"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `join()` function to combine all your array elements into single string value.

join() function will add a default separator (comma) for each pair of adjacent elements of the array. The separator is converted to a string and the output will be like,

```
letters.join(); //returns S,U,Z,D,A,R
```

To remove the ',' value you need to mention empty string ('') as parameter to join function. If separator is an empty string, all elements are joined without any characters in between them.

```
letters.join(''); //returns SUZDAR
```